# Date.Parse generating some random number while conversion - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I know there are loads of date time formatting question out here. But I am not able to solve this out.
I have a string in this format : "22 Oct 2013 17:51:10"
& I need to convert this into datetime format in jquery.
I tried Date.Parse as below :

```
a = Date.parse("10-22-2013, 17:51:10")
```

1382444470000
it is generating some random number.
Any hint, Why. Where I am doing this wrong.
or is there any better way to convert "22 Oct 2013 17:51:10" this into datetime"?

Edit : I cannot use external js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not random number .. but they are the milliseconds from January 1, 1970 to 10-22-2013, 17:51:10. Actually the Date.parse() method parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of January 1, 1970.

I think you should try follwing to get date from "10-22-2013, 17:51:10"

```
var a = new Date(Date.parse("10-22-2013, 17:51:10"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) for this task (and to save you from future headaches). I just tested it and it works great with your `10-22-2013, 17:51:10` string.

Comment: Thanks, it even works with "22 Oct 2013 17:51:10" but I am not supposed to use an external js :( Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
a = new Date(Date.parse("10-22-2013, 17:51:10"));
```

Converting the number of milliseconds back to date.

Answer (score 1):

This is not some random number. According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> Parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC